# Session variable are set to null between page

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

I have a solution with 2 projects : Core and Web. In the Core, I manage session I do something and I call this method :

```
public void SetLog()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Logged"] = true;
}
```

That's work.

When I change page (I use the ASP.NET 4.0 default template for testing), I click on the "About" link and I call this method :

```
public bool IsLogged()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Logged"] == null)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

On the About page, Session are null, normal ? how solve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you recompile in between? Is Core a web application?

Comment: Further to @DarinDimitrov's comments are both pages running under the same website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have 2 web applications: Core and Web hosted on 2 different domains: `http://localhost:1234` and `http://localhost:5678`. You seem to be setting the session variable inside the first web application but this session is only about the first application. As soon as you leave this application the other has a completely distinct session. Remember that sessions cannot be shared between ASP.NET applications. There are workarounds for this but out of the box it doesn't work.

Comment: Core is a "Class library". I start the application, on the default page, I do the "SetLog()" and direclty after a IsLogged() and IsLogged is true. I click on the "About" page, in the Page_Load, I call IsLogged() and the session is null.

Comment: That's very strange and shouldn't normally happen. Do you have cookies enabled in your web browser?

Comment: "Allow local data to be set" in Google chrome, then yes, it is.

Comment: And can you see the session cookie being sent in the request when you use the developer tools?